# Including a datapicker in an asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datapicker

I have an asp.net mvc4 application. in the view uploading i'd like to add a datapicker calendar so i modify the layout like this:

```
   <head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mon application ASP.NET MVC</title>
        <link href="~/akeo.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript" />

    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript" /> 
          <script>
              $(function () {
                  $("#datepicker").click(datepicker());
              });
    </script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
```

In the view Uploading.cshtml i put a text area for the datapicker:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading", "Akeo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Date d'expiration")
    <input type="text" name="duree" />
    <br />


    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />

}
```

[image: files]
The problem is when i click in text nothing is happened and the calendar did not appear.

What is the reason of this? How can i modify the code to correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript code should be:

```
$(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Are you javascript files loaded correctly? Please check the path.
I would recommend to use the tilde "~" or even better to use bundling, which has standard support in mvc4

Comment: e.g. <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
With bundling: e.g.: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Comment: ok. For your css files you need another path:
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: I added this `<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in the layout but the same result!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30817/discussion-between-kapsi-and-lamloumi)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the input field via the id `datepicker`. Either change the way you select the input field or add the id on the input field like this:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="duree" />
```

Or you could change the type of the input field to date and select it with this:

```
$('input[type="date"]')
```

And change the js to:

```
$('input[type="date"]').datepicker()
```

I would suggest you have a look at the HTML5 input types. The date type is getting more and more support: http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

**If you don't care about all of that just change these 2 parts:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#myDate" ).datepicker();
```

});

```
<input type="text" id="myDate" />
```

Comment: when i put `$('input[type="date"]')` in the place of the text i get a calendar but it is not datapicker even i deleted `$('input[type="date"]').datepicker()`

Comment: I've added a short version at the end of my answer. What happens if you change the 2 lines?

Comment: What happens if you remove your references to the jQuery scripts and css and replace them with the referenced scripts described here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/